# How to obtain the powerscript version and upgrade it in a batch script?

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file

I'm trying to check the powerscript version in a batch file and update the version if need be. Right now, I'm running $PSVersion to print out the version of powershell but I'm not sure how to parse it.

$PSVersion prints the entire table when all I need is the value(ex. 5.1.14393.103)

What I need to do is check that the $PSVersion is equal to version 5, and if not, then fetch the version and download it from the internet (I have this part covered)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check for `$PSVersionTable.PSVersion.Major` which in your example would be `5`

Answer (score 0):

This should work on PS 2.0 (the default for Win 7)

```
   if (($PSVersionTable.PSVersion.Major -lt 5) -and ($PSVersionTable.PSVersion.Minor -lt 1))
    {#put your upgrade code here
    }
 else
    {"PS is v 5.1"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method using the Windows registry:

```bat
@Echo Off

Set "bK=HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PowerShell"
Set "eK=PowerShellEngine"
Set "kV=PowerShellVersion"

For /F "Tokens=2*" %%A In ('Reg Query "%bK%\3\%eK%" /V "%kV%" 2^>Nul^
 ^|^|Reg Query "%bK%\1\%eK%" /V "%kV%" 2^>Nul') Do Set "pV=%%~nB"

If Not "%pV%" GEq "5" Echo Installing a newer version of PowerShell
Timeout -1
```

If you're happy with the output, just replace the string `Echo Installing a newer version of PowerShell` with your actual installation command and remove the `Timeout -1` line.